# How to set maximum value of angularjs polar chart axis?

Tags: angularjs

How to set maximum polar axis value to 100? Currently the maximum value depends on the highest value of data received.

Currently my current working code:

```js
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("ChartCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    
    $scope.data = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40];
    var sum = $scope.data.reduce(function add(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
    
    $scope.options = {
      pieceLabel: {
        render: function (args) {
          return args.label + " " + Math.round(args.value*100/sum,2)+"%";
        },
        fontColor: '#000',
        position: 'outside',
        segment: true
      }
    };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/beaver71/Chart.PieceLabel.js/master/build/Chart.PieceLabel.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChartCtrl">
  <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-polar-area"
         chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options">
  </canvas> 
</div>
```

Comment: Would be nice if you accept the answer :-)

Comment: I will accept your answer soon... don't worry ok.. @NicolasGehlert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can use the scale property on options

```
scale: {
    ticks: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        stepSize: 10
    }
}
```

I updated your example

```js
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("ChartCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    
    $scope.data = [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40];
    var sum = $scope.data.reduce(function add(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
    
    $scope.options = {
      pieceLabel: {
        render: function (args) {
          return args.label + " " + Math.round(args.value*100/sum,2)+"%";
        },
        fontColor: '#000',
        position: 'outside',
        segment: true,
      },
      scale: {
        ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            stepSize: 10
        }
      }
    };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/beaver71/Chart.PieceLabel.js/master/build/Chart.PieceLabel.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChartCtrl">
  <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-polar-area"
         chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options">
  </canvas> 
</div>
```

Comment: Before I accept this answer, how let the value of the scales only integer type? Since the current value is double type.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand, I only see int values

Comment: Can you see this pic?
blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/c9c3908e-05ff-4c27-a3d9-348747e1f945

Comment: You need to copy start from `blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/80368a10-4165-426e-9f1b-709ceead4930` and see it in your browser

Comment: no can't see the pic. maybe try to upload it to imgur

Comment: this is a completely different chart. If you only want int values as scale, use the scale and add step size 1 (or any other int)

Comment: I got your point, the `step`. But I need to reconfirm back. The chart is completely same. Anyway I need to test it first before I come back to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: well the chart in your imgur upload looks different than the one you provided in this thread or my example. It even has different values :D just hit run code snippet in one of the examples here