# How to make radar-chart start by 0?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart, radar-chart

I'm trying to create a radar chart in angularjs.

With some tutorials I managed to create some charts but they all don't start with 0.
Depending on what values I load into the radar-data, the axes are different but never start with 0.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KncBk.jpg) I uploaded a picture of my charts with different values.

This is how I create the chart in my angular app:

```
let values = crossfilterService.calculateRadar();
$scope.options = {
    scale: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        min: 0
    }
};
$scope.chartVisible = true;
$scope.labels = values[0]
$scope.data = [values[1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49197713/11662911)

All I had to do is change the chart options to this:

```
$scope.options = {
    scale: {
        ticks: {
            min: 0,
            //max: 100,
            //stepSize: 10
        }
    }
};
```